# set linear layout outside the scrollview

Tags: android, android-layout, uiscrollview

I want last two textview in the bottom of the screen and outside the scrollview...but with my code i can get the linear layout inside the scrollview, If i will define them outside the scrollview..It gives me error:root element must be formated at the last linear layout structure

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView2"
    android:background="@drawable/back1"
    android:scrollbars="horizontal" >

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >



    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="33dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
        android:text=""
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView4"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="33dp"
        android:text=""
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="33dp"
        android:text=""
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView5"
        android:layout_width="264dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:text=""
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF" />


        <TableLayout
            android:id="@+id/maintable"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dp" >
        </TableLayout>




        <TableLayout
            android:id="@+id/maintable1"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp" >
        </TableLayout>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView6"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@android:id/list"
        android:text=""
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF" />

    <ListView
        android:id="@android:id/list"
        style=" android:listViewStyle"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="70dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView6"
        android:layout_marginLeft="33dp"
        android:drawSelectorOnTop="true"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF" >

    </ListView>
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginBottom="0dp"

    android:orientation="horizontal"
      >
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView8"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="7dp"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:text=""
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:textColorLink="#FFFFFF" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView7"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="12dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="1dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
        android:text=""
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:textColorLink="#FFFFFF" />
    </LinearLayout>
     </LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

Comment: scrollview can only have 1 child

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this, add/change the design yourself :)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/darkblue">

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/scrollView"
        android:scrollbars="horizontal">
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical" >
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="33dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
                android:text="Hello"
                android:textColor="#FFFFFF" />
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView4"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="33dp"
                android:text="Hello"
                android:textColor="#FFFFFF" />
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView3"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="33dp"
                android:text="Hello"
                android:textColor="#FFFFFF" />
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView5"
                android:layout_width="264dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:text="Hello"
                android:textColor="#FFFFFF" />
            <TableLayout
                android:id="@+id/maintable"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="20dp" >
            </TableLayout>
            <TableLayout
                android:id="@+id/maintable1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp" >
            </TableLayout>
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView6"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@android:id/list"
                android:text="Hello"
                android:textColor="#FFFFFF" />
            <ListView
                android:id="@android:id/list"
                style=" android:listViewStyle"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="70dp"
                android:layout_below="@+id/textView6"
                android:layout_marginLeft="33dp"
                android:drawSelectorOnTop="true"
                android:textColor="#FFFFFF" >
            </ListView>
        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/scrollView"
        android:orientation="horizontal">
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView8"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="7dp"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
            android:text="Hello"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:textColorLink="#FFFFFF" />
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView7"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="12dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="1dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
            android:text="Hello"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:textColorLink="#FFFFFF" />
    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: But still in small screen size phones the scrollview is overlapping with the two textviews in the linearlayout...if you have any suggestion for that plz suggest me..thank you..

Comment: Ah, you will have to really work to fix this. As a shortcut try fixing the scroll view to 150 height (get the idea ?)

Comment: do 1 thing, set the height of the scroll View dynamically (programtically) to be half the size of the screen or whatever you seem fit.